# What is this syntax: using "this" in property in C#?

Tags: c#

I happened to read this line of code:

```
public MyArray this [int index]{
    get{
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

Where can I find the document on msdn about the syntax of using "this" in property?

And is there any book covers this kind of tricky syntax of C# other than the common stuff?

Comment: Thanks for that question. I also didn't know about indexers, and I think it is going to be quite useful to me as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

That's how you write an indexer:

[Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

[Indexers Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: +1 because you shouldn't be penalized for taking the time to format your answer better.  Also, because your low, low score makes me feel pity.